# How do I select network mode in Reliance 3g USB dongle

Tags: networking, usb, usb-modem, 3g

After googling on internet, I didn't find drivers for my zte modem.

In my area 3G coverage is low and I am unable to change from 3G to 2G network, neither manufacturer provides it's drivers for Linux. So:

1. How can I change network mode?  Is there any gui tool or any script?
2. I want to access it's file system as on windows, but it does not show in ubuntu.